# Rendering line breaks in HTML from SQL datasource

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datasource

I am returning multiple rows of a column as one single row and column:

```
SELECT STUFF((
                SELECT '<br/>' + Notes 
                FROM DailyTaskHours
                WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                    AND Notes <> ''
                    AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')
                )
```

I want to insert line breaks between each row that is being concatenated in ASP.NET but my approach is not working:

[image]

As you can see 
 is being replaced by the database engine with `&lt;br /&gt;` How do I get the linebreaks in the database so it will render spaced on the webpage?

Here is the entire control that I am working on for reference:

```
        <asp:GridView CssClass="hoursGrid" ID="hoursReportGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84"
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnRowDataBound="hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound" DataKeyNames="DifferentUsers, DoubleBookedFlag, PointPerson, Person">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" HeaderText="Person" SortExpression="Project" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Project" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="Project" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectType" HeaderText="Project Type" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sprint" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Theme" HeaderText="Theme" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Theme" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StoryNumber" HeaderText="Story Number" SortExpression="Story" ItemStyle-Width="6%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StoryTitle" HeaderText="Story Title" SortExpression="Story" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Effort" HeaderText="Effort" SortExpression="Effort" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="Task"  ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalEstimateHours" HeaderText="Original Estimate" SortExpression="OriginalEstimateHours" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday" HeaderText="Mon" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Monday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday" HeaderText="Tues" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Tuesday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday" HeaderText="Wed" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Wednesday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday" HeaderText="Thurs" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Thursday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday" HeaderText="Fri" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Friday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday" HeaderText="Sat" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Saturday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday" HeaderText="Sun" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sunday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="taskLinkButton" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("StoryTitle").ToString() != "" %>' runat="server" OnClick="taskLinkButton_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
            SelectCommand="
SELECT RowType AS RowType
    ,Person AS Person
    ,Project AS Project
    ,ProjectType AS ProjectType
    ,Theme AS Theme
    ,StoryNumber AS StoryNumber
    ,StoryTitle AS StoryTitle
    ,Effort AS Effort
    ,Task AS Task
    ,OriginalEstimateHours AS OriginalEstimateHours
    ,MondayHours AS Monday
    ,TuesdayHours AS Tuesday
    ,WednesdayHours AS Wednesday
    ,ThursdayHours AS Thursday
    ,FridayHours AS Friday
    ,SaturdayHours AS Saturday
    ,SundayHours AS Sunday
    ,TotalHours AS Total
    ,DifferentUsers AS DifferentUsers
    ,DoubleBookedFlag AS DoubleBookedFlag
    ,PointPerson AS PointPerson
FROM (
    -- DATE DISPLAY
    SELECT '1' AS RowType
        ,'' AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'Category' AS ProjectType
        ,'' AS Theme
        ,'Ticket #' AS StoryNumber
        ,'' AS StoryTitle
        ,'' AS Effort
        ,'' AS Task
        ,'' AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,'' AS Category
        ,'' AS IncidentNumber
        ,'' AS ApplicationName
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 0, @startDateParam)) = 2
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 0, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS MondayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateParam)) = 3
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS TuesdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 2, @startDateParam)) = 4
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 2, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS WednesdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 3, @startDateParam)) = 5
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 3, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS ThursdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 4, @startDateParam)) = 6
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 4, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS FridayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 5, @startDateParam)) = 7
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 5, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS SaturdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) >= 7
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startDateParam, @endDateParam) <= 5
                    THEN ''
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDateParam)) = 1
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDateParam), 101)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS SundayHours
        ,'' AS TotalHours
        ,'' AS DifferentUsers
        ,'' AS DoubleBookedFlag
        ,'' AS PointPerson
    --

    UNION ALL

    --
    -- GRAND TOTALS
    --
    SELECT '2' AS RowType
        ,'All Personnel' AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS ProjectType
        ,'' AS Theme
        ,'' AS StoryNumber
        ,'' AS StoryTitle
        ,'' AS Effort
        ,'Total:' AS Task
        ,'' AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,'' AS Category
        ,'' AS IncidentNumber
        ,'' AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Monday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Tuesday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Wednesday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Thursday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Friday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Saturday
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Sunday
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Total
        ,'' AS DifferentUsers
        ,'' AS DoubleBookedFlag
        ,'' AS PointPerson
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON DTH.EnteredBy = USR.DisplayName
    WHERE DTH.EnteredBy LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND 1 = CASE ISNUMERIC(@productId)
            WHEN 0
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NULL
                            OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            WHEN 1
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL
                            AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            END
        AND (
            (
                @orgTeamPK = '%'
                AND (
                    USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                    OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                )
            )
        AND (
            (
                STY.Number LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                STY.Title LIKE @search
                OR STY.Title IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                OR TSK.NAME IS NULL
                )
            )
        AND (
            (
                @theme = '%'
                AND (
                    dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) LIKE @theme
                    OR dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @theme != '%'
                AND dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) = @theme
                )
            )

    UNION ALL

    --
    -- Details by PERSON, PROJECT, SPRINT, STORY, TASK
    --
    SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
        ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                        )
                    THEN 'Kanban'
                WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                        )
                    THEN 'Sprint'
                ELSE SCY.Catagory
                END
            ) AS ProjectType
        ,dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) AS Theme
        ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS StoryNumber
        ,COALESCE(STY.Title, NSS.[Description]) AS StoryTitle
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS Effort
        ,COALESCE(TSK.[Name], (
                SELECT STUFF((
                            SELECT ' | ' + Notes 
                            FROM DailyTaskHours
                            WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                                AND Notes <> ''
                                AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            ), 1, 1, '')
                )) AS Task
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TSK.OriginalEstimateHours) AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,SCY.Catagory AS Category
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber AS IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DTH.Hours > 0
                        THEN DTH.[UserDifference]
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DifferentUsers
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DTH.Hours > 0
                        THEN DTH.DoubleBookedFlag
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS DoubleBookedFlag
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS PointPerson
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN SupportCatagory SCY ON NSS.CatagoryId = SCY.PK_SupportCatagory
    LEFT JOIN [Application] APP ON NSS.ApplicationId = APP.PK_Application
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON DTH.EnteredBy = USR.DisplayName
    WHERE DTH.EnteredBy LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND 1 = CASE ISNUMERIC(@productId)
            WHEN 0
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NULL
                            OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            WHEN 1
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL
                            AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            END
        AND (
            (
                @orgTeamPK = '%'
                AND (
                    USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                    OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                )
            )
        AND (
            (
                STY.Number LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                STY.Title LIKE @search
                OR STY.Title IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                OR TSK.NAME IS NULL
                )
            )
        AND (
            (
                @theme = '%'
                AND (
                    dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) LIKE @theme
                    OR dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @theme != '%'
                AND dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) = @theme
                )
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.EnteredBy
        ,PDT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Description]
        ,STY.[Number]
        ,STY.Title
        ,TSK.[Name]
        ,SCY.Catagory
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,APP.AppName
        ,STY.KanBanProductId
        ,STY.SprintId
        ,NSS.[Description]
        ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
        ,STY.Effort
        ,DTH.PointPerson
        ,DTH.NonScrumStoryId
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    --

    UNION ALL

    --
    -- Sub-TOTAL by PERSON
    --
    SELECT '4' AS RowType
        ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS ProjectType
        ,'' AS Theme
        ,'' AS StoryNumber
        ,'' AS StoryTitle
        ,'' AS Effort
        ,'Subtotal:' AS Task
        ,'' AS OriginalEstimateHours
        ,'' AS Category
        ,'' AS IncidentNumber
        ,'' AS ApplicationName
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
        ,'' AS DifferentUsers
        ,'' AS DoubleBookedFlag
        ,'' AS PointPerson
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
    LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON DTH.EnteredBy = USR.DisplayName
    WHERE DTH.EnteredBy LIKE @userParam
        AND ActivityDate >= @startDateParam
        AND ActivityDate <= @endDateParam
        AND 1 = CASE ISNUMERIC(@productId)
            WHEN 0
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NULL
                            OR PDT.PK_Product LIKE @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            WHEN 1
                THEN CASE 
                        WHEN DTH.TaskId IS NOT NULL
                            AND PDT.PK_Product = @productId
                            THEN 1
                        END
            END
        AND (
            (
                @orgTeamPK = '%'
                AND (
                    USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                    OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                )
            )
        AND (
            (
                STY.Number LIKE @search
                OR STY.Number IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                STY.Title LIKE @search
                OR STY.Title IS NULL
                )
            OR (
                TSK.NAME LIKE @search
                OR TSK.NAME IS NULL
                )
            )
        AND (
            (
                @theme = '%'
                AND (
                    dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) LIKE @theme
                    OR dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) IS NULL
                    )
                )
            OR (
                @theme != '%'
                AND dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number]) = @theme
                )
            )
    GROUP BY DTH.EnteredBy
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    ) AS My_View
ORDER BY Person
    ,RowType
    ,Project
    ,ProjectType
    ,StoryNumber
    ,StoryTitle
    ,Task
            ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userParam" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="startDateParam" Type="String" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="endDateParam" Type="String" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="orgTeamPK" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="productId" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="search" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="theme" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Don't concate `<br>` into the SQL query, instead with the array, you can map it later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database engine is not doing that, ASP.NET is doing it.  It is a security feature to help prevent XSS.

You can set the **HtmlEncode** property on the bound field like the example at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="City"
            htmlencode="false"
            headertext="City"/>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this feature. It certainly answers the specific question. Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

In your application, you probably want to do an `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` on the string.

From MSDN:

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission into a decoded string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

In fact, it's probably preferred to append the `<br />` in the application itself, not in the query. It's not typical to massage data in this way at the query itself. Typically the data being fetched for your application should not have any presentation-layer or view type stuff attached to it, unless that's exactly how it exists in the database. Save that work for your application. For example, if this is an MVC application, you may consider doing that kind of work in the controller.

**More...**

Now that I see the full context of your question from the code you've just posted, I'll add the same comment I make below to this answer for any future readers. It's been a while since I've been in ASP.NET WebForms land, so I may be a little rusty! My comment...

> There are better ways to handle this but I'm afraid it may be out of the scope of this question since it would also involve how you've created your data sources. If you're interested, a quick search resulted [in this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27260/Repeater-within-Gridview-in-C-ASP-NET-2-0) of a `Repeater` inside a `GridView` and a data source with two related data tables. It's an old example (.NET 2.0), but it may be still valid or at least should help lead you to a better example.

**And now for an alternative answer? ...**

I can think of another option specific to your question. In the query, instead of appending a `<br />`, you can append a straightforward new line (`\n` or char(10) in SQL). Then, instead of using an `asp:BoundColumn` for that field in your `GridView`, use an `asp:TemplateField` and inside the template, replace the `\n` with a `<br />`.  Like I said earlier, it's been a while since I've done WebForms, but I believe it would look something like:

```
<%#Eval("Task").Replace("\n", "<br />")%>
```

I suppose you could do similar using `HtmlDecode`, but I don't like seeing the HTML tags in those query results.

Comment: Thanks but the SQL is on the ASPX side... I tried changing the select line to: SELECT <% =HttpUtility.HtmlEncode('&lt;br /&gt;') %> + Notes  but am getting syntax errors.

Comment: `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` is a .NET method so it won't work in SQL.  Can you append the `<br />` in your code?  That is the preferred way to do it since then you're dealing with data exactly as it exists in the database itself.

Comment: Right, I embedded the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode in C# server tags because its a .NET ASPX page. How would I append <br /> in my code when I am using the query this way         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
            SelectCommand="query here">

Comment: What control are you using here? If you're using an ASP.NET `Repeater`, you have the option of adding a `<SeparatorTemplate>` and you can put the `<br />` in there.

Comment: Gridview control, I'll add the entire piece of code for reference.

Comment: Well, a `GridView` renders into an HTML table, right? But upon further review, I see that your query result is a concatenation of all of those notes so it's actually getting treated as one record. To properly utilize a `GridView`, you want each "note" to come back as an individual result within result set. Is there any reason you're not doing this already?

Comment: Yes, because of the relationship. There are many Notes associated with the other information shown on one row. This is why each is not being shown on a seperate row.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things. There are better ways to handle this but I'm afraid it may be out of the scope of this question since it would also involve how you've created your data sources. If you're interested, a quick search resulted in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27260/Repeater-within-Gridview-in-C-ASP-NET-2-0) of a `Repeater` inside a `GridView` and a data source with two related data tables. It's an old example (.NET 2.0), but it may be still valid or at least should help lead you to a better example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPLACE((SELECT '<br/>' + Notes 
               FROM DailyTaskHours
               WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                 AND Notes <> ''
                 AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,'&lt;br/&gt;','<br/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear use the following

```
SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT '<br/>' + Notes 
            FROM DailyTaskHours
            WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                AND Notes <> ''
                AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ), 1, 1, '')
            )
```

or

```
  SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT '<br/>' + Notes 
            FROM DailyTaskHours
            WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                AND Notes <> ''
                AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ), 1, 1, '')
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @DailyTaskHours TABLE (NonScrumStoryId INT, Notes NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @DailyTaskHours VALUES
(1, 'Note one for value one'),(1, 'Note two for value one'),(1, 'Note three for value one'),
(2, 'Note one for value Two'),(2, 'Note Two for value Two'),(2, 'Note Three for value two')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '<br/>' + Notes 
                FROM @DailyTaskHours
                WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                AND Notes <> ''
                AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
               .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 5, '') AS NotesList
FROM @DailyTaskHours DTH
GROUP BY NonScrumStoryId
```

**Resutl Set**

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                   NotesList                                    ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Note one for value one<br/>Note two for value one<br/>Note three for value one ║
║ Note one for value Two<br/>Note Two for value Two<br/>Note Three for value two ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Using CROSS APPLY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF(REPLACE(C.NotesList,'Break_Tag', '<br/>') , 1, 5, '') AS NotesList
FROM @DailyTaskHours DTH CROSS APPLY 
                         (SELECT 'Break_Tag' + Notes  [text()]
                          FROM @DailyTaskHours
                          WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
                          AND Notes <> ''
                          AND NonScrumStoryId = DTH.NonScrumStoryId
                          FOR XML PATH('')
                          )C(NotesList)
```